# Elasticsearch restart task hangs up in Ansible Playbook

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible

I am using ansible playbook to install elasticsearch and elasticsearch plugin. after successfully installation of Elasticsearch I written one ansible task to Restart Elasticsearch. Its restarting elasticsearch but ansible playbook hang up in this task. My ansible task is:

```
- name: "Ensure Elasticsearch is Running"
  service: name=elasticsearch state=restarted
```

I also tried with `shell: sudo service elasticsearch restart` but no luck.

**Elasticsearch Version** : 1.3.0
**Ansible Version**       : 1.5.5

Verbose Output for the task is :

```
<app101.host.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: prod on PORT 22 TO app101.host.com
<app101.host.com> REMOTE_MODULE service name=elasticsearch state=restarted
<app101.host.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1410327554.04-167734794521310 
   && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1410327554.04-167734794521310 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1410327554.04-167734794521310'
<app101.host.com> PUT /tmp/tmpjIMUkF TO /home/prod/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1410327554.04-167734794521310/service
<app101.host.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=yeztwzmmsgyvjjqmmunnvtbopcplrbso] 
  password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo SUDO-SUCCESS-yeztwzmmsgyvjjqmmunnvtbopcplrbso; /usr/bin/python /home/prod/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1410327554.04-167734794521310/service;
  rm -rf /home/prod/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1410327554.04-167734794521310/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
```

Does anyone face similar issue?

Comment: Run your playbook with `-vvv` and see if it complains about anything.

Comment: @Mxx: thanks for the reply . I checked in verbose output but unable to find any error message. Also I try to run playbook with `-K` but still remain same.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
- name: Restart elasticsearch service
  sudo: yes
  shell: "/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop || true && /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix this problem.  Cause of the issue is I am using old version of service wrapper script for elasticsearch. After update  `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` everything is working fine.